# Groovy: Adding elements to a collection

Tags: groovy, collections, jenkins-groovy

I've the following collection

```
def a = [
    b:[
        [
            c: "x",
            d: ["y","z"]
         ]
        ],
    b1:[
        [
            c: "x1",
            d: ["y1","z1"]
         ]
        ]
]
```

I want to add a new element "w" to d:["y", "z"] to have this d:["y", "z", "w"]

I've tried a.put(d:"w"), a.add(d:"w") but getting exception

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.put() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [w]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have take into account all your nesting here.  You have a map to
list to map.  The main problem is the list now, since your example makes
it not clear, how many list items `b` could hold.  So the solution for
your *exact* example is:

```
a.b[0].d << "w"
```